Nested elements in selenium... do I need to get all of them?
I'm doing some scraping and automation using selenium. My question is exactly what I putted on the title. Say I have something like:
<div id = "dsopdoaspdk">
   <div id = "owpowqkeqwop">
     <div id = "wewqopewqkeop">
        <div class = "kdmkdmqwopeop">
            <span class = "wopqqwope">
               <a id = "dlopkeop">

and I want to get only the a class for clicking in the link. On the XPATH I have to put all the divs nested or can I get something like getting only the most outer div("dsopdoaspdk") and the <a id? or, better, can I get something like find_element(By.ID, "dlopkeop") ignoring all the divs?
I'm trying to reduce the amount of code not putting all these long div class names.

This seems potentially related: xpath: select parent and filtered children

You don't need rucursive search all divs. You may use find_all method from BeautifulSoup for finding all links and its classes:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.w3schools.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

for elem in soup.find_all('a', href=True, id=True):
    if elem.get('id'):
        print("Found the URL:", elem['href'])
        print("The ID of current url:", elem.get('id'))
        print("The class of current url:", elem.get_attribute_list('class')[0])

Now you may pass elem['href'] to Selenium. This way allow dynamically handling all links at page

You can always use methods of selenium,
For this particular example of yours you can try using find_element method
so you need only one line to click the  tag which has that id
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dlopkeop').click()

